# WPF Datagrid scrolling causes validation to fire

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, scroll, datagrid

What is the reason behind this behaviour? Even though no edit has been made, scrolling over Datagrid causes the validation rule defined as

```html
<DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
  <local:RowValidationChecker ValidationStep="CommittedValue"  ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
</DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
```

to fire. Any ideas on how to disable this behaviour, or perhaps to check whether an edit has been issued or not so that even if the validation fires, it could be put in a conditional branch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an event fired by PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown for your grid ?
      If so, clicking on scrollbars can fire it.

You can filter this behaviour :

```
    private void DataGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyObject src = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);
        if (src.GetType() == typeof(ContentPresenter))
        {
          --- your event code ----
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but no. the scroll I mentioned above is done by the mouse wheel.

Comment: Sorry i thought this could helps you, I had a similar scroll bars click issue.

Comment: this does not helps us. it kills us. my precious.